# ORACLE SQL join tables without excluding data with no content

Tags: sql, oracle

Iam working on a SQL query in our management system with article features in several thousand tables. When I join tables I use the article SKU/ID to connect them.

There are many articles where not all features are maintained but which I need in my query. For example there is inner material. We have jackets which have inner material, but jeans not.
If I join the table for material, the jeans aren't in it, because there's no content in that specific field.

Is it possible to say SQL, just fill the empty field with something, but give it out at least?

Example code below

```
select 
ARFORM || ARQUAL || AFFB as "item_sku",
ARMATZUSKZ1 as "fabric_type1",
ARMATZUSPROZ1 as "fabric_type1p"

from ARTIKEL

join ARTIKEL_MATZUSAMMENSETZUNG on
ARTIKEL.ARFORM = ARTIKEL_MATZUSAMMENSETZUNG.FORM and
ARTIKEL.ARQUAL = ARTIKEL_MATZUSAMMENSETZUNG.QUAL
```

Comment: Simply `coalesce(columnname, '<no value text>')`? Or do you want a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have the options of either `OR` the columns e.g :

```
( ARTIKEL.ARFORM IS NULL OR ARTIKEL.ARFORM = ARTIKEL_MATZUSAMMENSETZUNG.FORM )
```

or `NVL` the values with what you're comparing to so that you get a match if either is present:

```
NVL(ARTIKEL.ARFORM, ARTIKEL_MATZUSAMMENSETZUNG.FORM) = NVL(ARTIKEL_MATZUSAMMENSETZUNG.FORM,ARTIKEL.ARFORM)
```